# Merge two XML files with Delphi XE10

Tags: xml, delphi, merge

I try to merge two XML files (created with MSword) with the code bellow but although it runs without any error, i receive an error message when i try to open the merged file. Actually the merged file contains the first's file content plus only the first line of the second (the line " < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ? > "). No merged contents!

// button select the first file then button2 selects the second and merges them

```
uses XML.xmlDoc,XML.XMLintf;

var XMLDoc1, XMLDoc2 : TXMLDocument;

procedure TForm30.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
        XMLDoc1 := TXMLDocument.Create(self);
        XMLDoc1.Active := True;
        XMLDoc1.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.filename);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm30.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var ANode: IXMLNode;
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
        XMLDoc2 := TXMLDocument.Create(self);
        xmlDoc2.Active:= True;
        XMLDoc2.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.filename);
        ANode:= XMLDoc2.ChildNodes[0].CloneNode(True);
        xmlDoc1.ChildNodes.add(ANode);
        xmlDoc2.Active:= False;
        xmlDoc1.SaveToFile('c:\' + 'Merge.xml');
        XMLDoc1.free;
        XMLDoc2.free;
        aNode.free;
    end;
end;
```

What i'm doing wrong, please ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: XML can only have 1 top-level document element, but your code is trying to create 2 top-level elements. Also, you are not taking into account that `XMLDoc2.ChildNodes[0]` may not be the top-level document element, it could be other node types.  In this case, it sounds it is the prolog node. You should use the `XMLDoc2.DocumentElement` property instead.

Comment: thanks Remy, you are right. But I don't know how can I force the two docs to be merged. Any help will be invaluable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML can only have 1 top-level document element, but your code is trying to create 2 top-level elements.

Also, you are not taking into account that `XMLDoc2.ChildNodes[0]` may not be the top-level document element. It can be other node types, like processing instructions, etc.  In this case, it sounds it is the XML prolog node. To access the top-level element node, use the `XMLDoc2.DocumentElement` property instead.

If you need to add the second document's top-level element as a child of the first document's top-level element, then try something more like this:

```
uses
  Xml.XmlDoc, Xml.XmlIntf;

var
  XMLDoc1, XMLDoc2 : IXMLDocument;

procedure TForm30.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    XMLDoc1 := LoadXMLDocument(OpenDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm30.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ANode: IXMLNode;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    XMLDoc2 := LoadXMLDocument(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    ANode := XMLDoc2.DocumentElement.CloneNode(True);
    XMLDoc1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Add(ANode);
    XMLDoc1.SaveToFile('C:\Merge.xml');
    XMLDoc1 := nil;
    XMLDoc2 := nil;
  end;
end;
```

On the other hand, if you need to preserve both documents' top-level elements, you will have to create a new document with its own top-level element and then add the two documents as its children:

```
uses
  Xml.XmlDoc, Xml.XmlIntf;

var
  XMLDoc1, XMLDoc2 : IXMLDocument;

procedure TForm30.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    XMLDoc1 := LoadXMLDocument(OpenDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm30.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ANode: IXMLNode;
  XMLDoc3: IXMLDocument;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    XMLDoc2 := LoadXMLDocument(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    XMLDoc3 := NewXMLDocument;
    ANode := XMLDoc3.AddChild('merged');
    ANode.ChildNodes.Add(XMLDoc1.DocumentElement.CloneNode(True));
    ANode.ChildNodes.Add(XMLDoc2.DocumentElement.CloneNode(True));
    XMLDoc3.SaveToFile('C:\Merge.xml');
    XMLDoc1 := nil;
    XMLDoc2 := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, the second code snippet produces an XML file but it isn't readable from MSword. I need to merge two MSword docs (saved as XML) to produce a new MSword doc (in XML format). I can do this by code using Word OLE (open the first file, append the second and save the result as XML) but i want to do it using XML interfaces because the user  may has not MSWord installed but some other editor.

Comment: Without seeing your actual XML documents, or what the merged XML is supposed to look like, I can't help you further. Please edit your question to provide those details, as well as the OLE code that works. You can't simply "merge" independent XML documents and expect them to work correctly. XML has structure to it. The OLE approach is more likely accessing the MSWord documents as OLE objects, merging their **textual context** together into a single object, and then creating a new single XML document from that object's text. That is a lot harder to do if you just focus on the XML layer by itself

Comment: @JimPapas: I asked you to [EDIT YOUR QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40600016/edit) to add the XML + code.  Don't post them in comments, they do not belong there.  In any case, the OLE code you show is doing exactly what I predicted - it is taking the **text** of the second document, appending it to the **text** of the first document, and then saving the new **text** to a single file. Concatenating XML documents together is not the same thing. You will have to extract the **text** from the two XML documents, merge them together, and create a new XML document for that merged **text**

Comment: @JimPapas: which is a different scenario than what you originally asked for.  So if you can't figure out how to extract MSWord's textual content from its XML files, then please post a new question about that.